# Trouble with VS2019 Installer

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019

I installed the Visual Studio 2019 Community and used it normally for several months. Then I need to add a component and for this I open the installer. Before opening it asked for updates and I successfully updated the installer, but after that I noticed that the installer does not see the already installed version of the studio.

How to fix this problem without uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Please let us know any progress.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually**, the installed VS record of VS Installer exists under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances`.

This is the structure in my side:

[image]

I think you have missed that folder in your agent and it may be accidentally deleted by some malicious software. If no records were found at the recycle bin, I think you have to reinstall all VS and VS Installer.

**Steps for reinstallation**：

**1)** See if you have this file on your machine: `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`

**If so**, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param InstallCleanup.exe -full

**If not**, please manually delete the `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` folder

**2)** Relaunch the newly downloaded `vs_enterprise.exe` (or `vs_professional.exe` or `vs_community.exe`…)

**3)** Allow the first step to install the installer

**4)** Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it

**5)** Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS

**6)** Verify that your initial install location for VS is removed.If it is not, delete it manually.

**7)** Then relaunch `vs_community.exe` and install VS